# Simple gSheet Query returns wrong values for Count function based on data in columns not evaluated in the query

Tags: sql, select, count

The problem is that a count function evaluating only column A get different results depending on what's in other columns if those columns are included in the range even if not included in the select criteria.

This is a stripped down version of the problem. The additional columns are needed because of a where condition dependent on data in a different column.  But the problem manifests even when the where condition is removed from the query.

A sample spreadsheet including a loom vid of the problem can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJ6qaTcEiXZlzD1opxMHNhFyIBM1CDJPCJ5gr9x_32k/edit?usp=sharing

Any insights or work-arounds will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There've been 18 views and no insights or work-arounds.  Nor have I found a work-around so I'm assuming this is a gSheet bug.  How does one go about submitting a bug to G?